# Is Remote blob storage secure?

Tags: rbs

As I understand RBS is the data save in to file system as blog object and have grant permission to Sharepoint only. My question is if I have Admin user of database server, can i access blob directory and see the data?

Answer (score 1):

RBS utilize MS SQL [filestream](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx) feature inside. Filestream files have set the same permissions as in the database. So if you have access to SharePoint database you can also access files representing externally stored data.

Comment: So people just go to the blob folder and see all naked file without any encoding? Thank you

Comment: Yes, files are protected only by file permissions.

Comment: Please notice that files can be encrypted, also by default they have another filename (BLOB-name) This would make it less easy to access specific data